# How should I break this block into smaller functional units?

Tags: java, oop

I'm writing an application to help my friends run some numbers to balance a game.

This has become a larger project than I initially thought it would be, due to the large number of classes and stat variables.

I'm in the middle of making `HeroObject`s which are supposed to represent the stats of the hero.  This object is extended by each class (i.e. `Marksman`) which provides specific functionality related to the class.  I'm reading these heros in via a `csv` file so multiple classes and skill formulas can be tested at once.  Here's the function I'm using to make the `HeroObject`s:

```
private HeroObject makeHero(String[] heroLine) {
        switch(heroLine[11].toLowerCase()) {
            case "rogue":
                return new Rogue(Integer.valueOf(heroLine[0]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[1]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[2]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[3]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[4]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[5]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[6]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[7]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[8]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[9]), 
                heroLine[10]);
            case "marksman":
                return new Marksman(Integer.valueOf(heroLine[0]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[1]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[2]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[3]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[4]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[5]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[6]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[7]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[8]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[9]), 
                heroLine[10]);
            case "knight":
                return new Knight(Integer.valueOf(heroLine[0]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[1]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[2]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[3]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[4]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[5]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[6]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[7]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[8]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[9]), 
                heroLine[10]);
            case "lancer":
                return new Lancer(Integer.valueOf(heroLine[0]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[1]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[2]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[3]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[4]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[5]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[6]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[7]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[8]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[9]), 
                heroLine[10]);
            case "windadept":
                return new WindAdept(Integer.valueOf(heroLine[0]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[1]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[2]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[3]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[4]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[5]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[6]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[7]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[8]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[9]), 
                heroLine[10]);
            case "wateradept":
                return new WaterAdept(Integer.valueOf(heroLine[0]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[1]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[2]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[3]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[4]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[5]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[6]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[7]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[8]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[9]), 
                heroLine[10]);
            case "lightningadept":
                return new LightningAdept(Integer.valueOf(heroLine[0]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[1]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[2]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[3]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[4]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[5]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[6]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[7]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[8]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[9]), 
                heroLine[10]);
            case "lightadept":
                return new LightAdept(Integer.valueOf(heroLine[0]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[1]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[2]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[3]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[4]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[5]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[6]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[7]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[8]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[9]), 
                heroLine[10]);
            case "iceadept":
                return new IceAdept(Integer.valueOf(heroLine[0]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[1]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[2]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[3]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[4]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[5]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[6]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[7]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[8]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[9]), 
                heroLine[10]);
            case "fireadept":
                return new FireAdept(Integer.valueOf(heroLine[0]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[1]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[2]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[3]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[4]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[5]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[6]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[7]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[8]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[9]), 
                heroLine[10]);
            case "earthadept":
                return new EarthAdept(Integer.valueOf(heroLine[0]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[1]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[2]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[3]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[4]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[5]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[6]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[7]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[8]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[9]), 
                heroLine[10]);
            case "darkadept":
                return new DarkAdept(Integer.valueOf(heroLine[0]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[1]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[2]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[3]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[4]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[5]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[6]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[7]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[8]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[9]), 
                heroLine[10]);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I don't have to point out how much of this is repetitive code, but I'm unsure how I can break the case section into its own class without checking what the class is again.

**tl;dr:**
Each class is extending `HeroObject` and thus has the same constructor but I still need these to be created via their respective interfaces.  How can I functionally separate the following blocks:

```
return new SomeClass(Integer.valueOf(heroLine[0]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[1]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[2]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[3]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[4]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[5]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[6]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[7]), 
                Integer.valueOf(heroLine[8]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[9]), 
                heroLine[10]);
```

Comment: @duffymo Thank you for making this more readable.

Comment: are you sure you need different classes for your types of hero? couldn't you have the class be a property of the hero, in which case you can create the hero first, then add the class property depending on the input.

Comment: It actually is a property of HeroObject.  The reason there is differentiation is the style of leveling being used.  Each class has its own stat changes each level and attempting to write a levelUp function that could handle every class was going to monolithic compared to taking advantage of inheritance.

Comment: you can easily move that in a delegate function in a separate class object. The question being whether your class-specific inherited method use the 11 properties of the hero all the time.

Comment: @njzk2 They do.  Indexes 0 - 9 contain stats that are needed to do the calculations later, index 10 contains the formula.

Comment: then you can reverse what I said: create a specific class for each class of hero, but use a container to hold the data. Create the stats container first, then pass it to whatever class you are using for your hero class.

Comment: @njzk2 Thank you, I'm definitely gonna do that.  It'll make changes later much easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should certainly separate reading the Excel file and creating instances from the `Hero` class.

I'd create a `HeroFactory` (aka virtual constructor) that could give me instances of `Hero` and any other subclass.

It looks like the columns in the Excel file are the same for each case.  Instead of a switch statement, pass in the type of object you want.

```
public class HeroFactory {

    public static final Hero createHero(Class heroClass) {
      // create the type of Hero here based on Class passed in.  You can use reflection to make it clean.  No switch needed.
    }
}
```

It'd be easy to cut down on the amount of code with another constructor:

```
public class Hero {
    public Hero(String [] parameters) {
        // initialize your stuff by iterating over the parameters  instead of passing 11 values.
    }
}
```

Comment: @duffymo Thank you!

Comment: `You can use reflection to make it clean`. An odd formulation, to say the least.

Comment: Why so?  I'd write more to demonstrate, but I'm being lazy.

Answer (score 2):

On the one side, you are on a good path: you are (somehow) turning towards a factory pattern. Of course, as duffymo says, this could be extended.

But that won't solve your real problem: and that is - you are using low-level abstractions! You see, you are using an array of strings to represent important information; and thus your factory code is utterly complicated.

Meaning: in well-designed OO setting, you should avoid objects that need more than 2, 3 parameters upon creation. In other words: you really have to step back and figure how to improve the quality of the *model* you are basing your design on. You see, classes/interfaces, they all exist to provide useful abstractions. Your classes fail to do that; because in essence, you are switching on strings; and building everything from strings.

The underlying reason for that: probably CSV is a **bad** format for data that contains META information?

Long story short: you are trying to make your code work with data that carries insufficient meta information. If that is an option, you should step back and consider if you could change from CSV to JSON for example.

Meaning: don't put lines of strings into files. Put *objects* into your file; and read them back from there.

If all of that is not possible; then there are only two choices in my eyes: as duffymo suggests; consider using reflections. But ... doing such "dynamic" things ... that is not something that Java is really good at. If you really need a lot of "code dynamics"; based on the data you are working with - maybe other languages would get you there faster. You know, meta programming is much easier to do in python, ruby, ...

Comment: It can still be simplified by passing in Class and using reflection.  Simple.  No switch needed.  Extensible, too.

Comment: The main reason I'm using `String`s to hold the data (I'm just as annoyed with it as you) is because some of the data has to be in a `String`.  Mainly class names and equations to be tested.

Comment: I'd love to use a `JSON`, but I'm 99.9% sure about two of the people that are going to end up using this to test are the only ones that have an idea how to make a `JSON` file and the others won't be amiable to learning.

Comment: JSON, XML - you can overload that virtual constructor to take those as well.  Provide unit tests to show how to do it.  They'll get used to the idea quickly enough.

Comment: @duffymo It took me an hour to explain how to make classes in `RPGMaker MV`.  And that provides a friendly GUI.  In the end, this will likely change in version 2.  Right now I'm forcing command line so I don't have to do GUI scripting right away, but that's next and then I'm gonna change the data type.

Comment: You're wise to defer UI and start with command line.  I like your style.  Get all this stuff working and then worry about GUI.  Good luck.

Comment: @duffymo Maybe, if you want to continue this discussion; could you please do that in a discussion ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try making another HeroObject Constructor but have it take in an Array of ints and the last value.

```java
public HeroObject (int[] heroValues, Object heroLine )
{
    this(heroValues[0], heroValues[1], 
         heroValues[2], heroValues[3], 
         heroValues[4], heroValues[5], 
         heroValues[6], heroValues[7],
         heroValues[8], heroValues[9], 
         heroLine);
}
```

Build the int array before the switch.

```java
int[] heroValues = new int[] {
Integer.valueOf(heroLine[0]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[1]), 
Integer.valueOf(heroLine[2]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[3]), 
Integer.valueOf(heroLine[4]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[5]), 
Integer.valueOf(heroLine[6]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[7]), 
Integer.valueOf(heroLine[8]), Integer.valueOf(heroLine[9])};
```

Then call the constructor like so.

```java
new SomeClass(heroValues, heroLine[10]);
```